# How To Create an Action Class?? To register with "WPF" task schedule queue using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, taskscheduler

I am creating a WPF application. I am implementing the MVVM pattern. I have a UI which returns the source path, destination path and a list of DateTimes which is a queue of times to execute for then next seven days.

In this function I want to be able to take the list of scheduled dates and register a task using my Schedule Helper Class

This is my ViewModel which has access to my Directory Helper class instance and a model instances bound to my UI.

Below is my function which get called after my fields are populated and the button is submitted

```
//THIS FUNCTION IS BOUND TO A BUTTON ON THE PAGE
private void startBackUp(object param) {

    // LIST OF DATETIMES
    List<DateTime> backUpQueue = new List<DateTime>();

    // FUNCTION IN THIS VIEW MODEL THAT RETURNS 
    // CURRENT INSTANCE OF THE MODEL WITH THE USERS SELECTION
    backUpQueue = populateBackUpQueue(backUpQueue);  

    // THIS IS THE ACTION I WANT TO PERFORM 
    // FRUNCTION FROM INSTANCE OF A HELPER CLASS
   DirectoryCommand.DirectoryCopy(BackUp.SourcePath,BackUp.DestinationPath, true);
}
```

I want to create a task which runs Directory copy function using this scheduled Task helper method

SchedualeTask.cs

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
using System;

namespace BackUpProject.Helper
{
    class SchedualeWindowsTasks
    {
        public TaskService ts { get; set; }

        public SchedualeWindowsTasks()
        {
            // INSTANCE OF A TASK SERVICE
            TaskService ts = new TaskService();
        }

        private void CreateNewWindowsScheduale(Action<DateTime>schedualedAction) { 
            // Create a new task definition and assign properties
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "THIS SHOULD BE MY TASK";

            // This will be the date time to execute this task
            // I can the use DailyTrigger to repeat weekly

            //Currently exceute every other day
            td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger(2));

            // This needs to be my DirectoryCopy() function with parameters
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

            // need to register it so can delete by calling DeleteTask("Test")
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);
        }
    }
}
```

I simply want to take by source path and directory path and execute my directoryCopy function on every DateTime given by the user and then use a weekly Trigger to repeat every week until Deleted by the user, but I handle delete later.

My question is by maintaining the MVVM pattern what is the favorable method of implementing such a task.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to have you go about your scheduling, but if you are really interested in MVVM, `startBackUp` should be an `ICommand` implementation as a property on the viewmodel.

Comment: Looking at this more, I think you just need to create some kind of "Task" class to wrap up all the details of the task you want to schedule.  You can then populate these and pass them in to your scheduler.

Comment: Ok Sounds Good, So If I had an Icommand bound to my button on my page, What would the Icommand do ? would it be a Scheduale Task Icommand.and what would I have my onExecute method do?

Comment: It looks like you already have a class, `ExecAction` that your commmand would create, and pass in to `CreateNewWindowsScheduale` along with the date.  That function would then go about attaching it to the scheduler.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what to do, thank you.